# convert roman numbers to decimal numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code to convert roman numbers so for most numbers its working fine but as soon as I add like IV its giving me 6 instead of 4 or XIV it's giving me 16 instead of 14 so I know I have small problem but I can't figure it out please help!

```
def romaine_v1(mdg):
    values = {"I":1,"II":2,"III":3, "IV":4, "V":5, "X":10, "D":500, "C":100, "M":1000}
return sum(map(lambda x: values[x], mdg))

def romaine_v2(string):
    result = 0
    table = table=[['M',1000],['D',500],['C',100],['X',10],['V',5],['I',1]]
    for pairs in table:
        for letter, value in table:
        while string.startswith(letter):
            result += value
            string = string[len(pairs[0]):]
    return result


ch = input("Entrez un nombre romain en utilisant les lettres M, D, C, X et I:")


print(romaine_v1(ch))
print(romaine_v2(ch))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `string.startswith` and loop through `table`, you run across `I` first, rather than `IV`. This causes you to add 1. Later (on the next iteration), you hit the `V` and add 5. The same problem would happen with, for example, `MXM` (1990), `IC` (99), and any other number which involves the reversal of letters to indicate "x less than y."

The solution is to check whether a given character's numeric value is less than the following character's value.